# How to track File Downloads on Server?

Tags: php, file, download, analytics, tracking

I have place an exe file on my server in a directory and shared the link of that file on hundreds of sites (that are not mine) on the web. I have attached different ids at the end of each link. Now I am having downloads of my file that is on the server. I want to track the site from which the link is clicked ( the sits/s can be any of the site with download link and id on the web) and also some other stats related to the downloads.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you could simply reverse DKasipovic's answer with a bit of rewriting.  For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).(exe|zip)$ /download.php?file=$1.$2 [R,L]
```

Then in download.php:

```
$filename = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'file', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$path     = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".filename;
$referer  = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {

   //assume you are tracking via Google Analytics - add UA and filename

   $data = array(
    'v' => 1,
    'tid' =>'UA-XXXXXXXX-X',
    'cid' => gen_uuid(), 
    'dh' => 'example.com',
    't' => 'event', 
    'ec' => 'Download', 
    'ea' => "$filename", 
    'el' => "$referer",
    'ev' => "",
    'ni'=>1
    );

    $url = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect'; 
    $content = http_build_query($data);
    $content = utf8_encode($content); 
    $user_agent = 'OFFLINE TRACK'; 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // now give them their file
    $fsize = filesize($path);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=".$path_parts["basename"]."");
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private");
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;

function gen_uuid() {
  return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
  mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
  mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
  mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
  mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
  mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
  );
}
```

You can report all sorts of data back to GA, see  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#content

Answer (score 1):

Since you have provided direct access link for your .exe file, only thing you can do to track the downloads is view it in apache access log (or access log of whatever web server software you are using).

Or if you are using shared hosting (presumably with cPanel), you probably already have some log statistics tools like awstats.

Better way would be to write small script (download.php for example), which would write entry to database when opened and then forward the exe file to the user. That way you could have a database of each download.

Then you would share `http://yoursite.com/download.php` which would act as a download counter.

Comment: I have already shared the link to hundreds of sites along with ids and I cant do anything with them. I am a newbie cant write the script. If you can help me in this regard. I will be very much thankful to you.

Comment: There is not much I can do for you. Do you host your own server, or are you on shared (cPanel or similar) hosting?

Comment: I have my own server
@D.Kasipovic

Comment: Then open `/var/log/apache2/access.log` or similar, and parse it, grep it, sed it, whatever to see when your file has been downloaded. Something like `cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep "yourfile"` should get you started. If you pipe that to `wc -l` you will get number of downloads.